# Is it possible to run an userscript on chrome://chromewebdata/ in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, userscripts

I want to redirect from a page that always result in HTTP 500, to the new page for the website.

I have made the userscript but it doesn't run, because the page is chrome://chromewebdata/ not http://xxx.xxx/yyy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not using a user script.

I would suggest looking into a Chrome Extension using the experimental webNavigation API and the associated "onError" callback.

http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/trunk/experimental.webNavigation.html#event-onErrorOccurred